# How to convert the string data from a column into list using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

We need to convert string data from a column into list format.
We have a csv format file with 7 columns, where we needs to make the change in categories column and save the data into the same csv file.

**Input Data:**

```
categories
2,3,6
2,4
5
1,5,6
1,2,3
```

Output:

```
categories
["2","3","6"]
["2","4"]
["5"]
["1","5","6"]
["1","2","3"]
```

Code applied:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv")
my_list = np.array(data['categories'].values.tolist())
```

After conversion how we can save the data into the same CSV file.

Comment: What's wrong with your code, what are your debugging steps?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski -  It is giving the output as ['2,3,6' '243' '5' ... '1,2,3']

Comment: `input data` - is that the csv file, or a column of the dataframe?  You need to be very clear about what you have if you want clear answers.  We can guess wrong if the question is incomplete.

Comment: @hpaulj - This is just an column in the csv file . The CSV contains Categories along with 7 more columns, but we need to convert only the categories column

Comment: I still don't have a clear idea of what the csv looks like or what the dataframe loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv", sep=r'\s+')
df['categories'] = df['categories'].str.split(',')
df.to_csv('1.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

1.csv file:

```
categories
['2', '3', '6']
['2', '4']
['5']
['1', '5', '6']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: getting the following error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 54 fields in line 7, saw 58" on this line df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv", sep=r'\s+') as the CSV file have few more columns

Comment: What is the delimiter in your CSV?

Comment: Delimiter used is csv file is commas ", "

Comment: So that won't work then right? You have a column with commas and the column separator is also a comma. Unless the column with the commas is surrounded by "

Comment: So how i can overcome this issue ?

Comment: There's no easy way to get around it. You may have to change the delimiter in the CSV file when it's being saved. Where are you getting the CSV file form?

Answer (score -1):

```
# Importing library 
import csv 
  
# data to be written in csv file 
my_list = np.array(data['categories'].values.tolist())
  
# opening the csv file in 'w+' mode 
file = open("D:\data.csv", 'w+', newline ='') 
  
# writing the data into the file 
with file:     
    write = csv.writer(file) 
    write.writerows(my_list)
```